# json object has key with spaces and parenthesis

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON I am trying to parse the first object key/val `Member ID (U1)` but I am getting undefined. Any solution around this? I am retrieving the data from an external 3rd party API.

```
var data = { data:
               [ { 'Member ID (U1)': 'monkey!',
                   MID: '123456',
                   'Advertiser Name': 'SampleAdvertiser',
                   'Order ID': 'ORDER12345',
                   'Transaction Date': '6/16/20',
                   'Transaction Time': '11:13:14',
                   SKU: 'SKU12345',
                   Sales: '100',
                   '# of Items': '1',
                   'Total Commission': '12.8',
                   'Process Date': '6/17/20',
                   'Process Time': '11:20:36' }]
            }

data.data.forEach(transaction => {
    var member_id = transaction['Member ID (U1)']
    console.log(member_id) //prints undefined, expected monkey!
})
```

edit - turns out there is some weird special character in front of the "M". ended up copying that character in the for loop and now it works. Thank you SO!

Comment: That is not JSON. Could you check the usage description of the `json` tag?

Comment: You had symbol in that `'Member ID (U1)'`. Without it it gives the expected result.(Like in that code snippet)

Comment: I tried to turn the script into a code snippet, but SO removed the special character once I saved the snippet. So I reverted my update of your question. The special character sits just before the initial "M".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key `﻿Member ID (U1)` contains a [ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE' (U+FEFF)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm) so when you try to access it without that invisible character then it is undefined. You can access the key like this:

`var member_id = transaction["\uFEFFMember ID (U1)"]`

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = { data:
           [ { 'Member ID (U1)': 'monkey!',
               MID: '123456',
               'Advertiser Name': 'SampleAdvertiser',
               'Order ID': 'ORDER12345',
               'Transaction Date': '6/16/20',
               'Transaction Time': '11:13:14',
               SKU: 'SKU12345',
               Sales: '100',
               '# of Items': '1',
               'Total Commission': '12.8',
               'Process Date': '6/17/20',
               'Process Time': '11:20:36' }]
        }

data.data.forEach(transaction => {
    var member_id = transaction['Member ID (U1)'];
    console.log(member_id); //prints monkey!
})
```

worked as expected!
https://codepen.io/stewardtz/pen/rNxeREN

You have some extra char inside single quotes before words "Member ID (U1)". Please check my codepen example (open Console tab on the bottom).

Answer (score 1):

There are special / hidden characters in 'Member ID (U1)'. Not sure what the characters are. How did you get the data?

I copied the key value from the var data declaration, pasted in the foreach code and it worked. see in https://jsfiddle.net/mk4q3x9L/

```
var data = { data:
               [ { 'Member ID (U1)': 'monkey!',
                   MID: '123456',
                   'Advertiser Name': 'SampleAdvertiser',
                   'Order ID': 'ORDER12345',
                   'Transaction Date': '6/16/20',
                   'Transaction Time': '11:13:14',
                   SKU: 'SKU12345',
                   Sales: '100',
                   '# of Items': '1',
                   'Total Commission': '12.8',
                   'Process Date': '6/17/20',
                   'Process Time': '11:20:36' }]
            }


data.data.forEach(transaction => {
   var member_id = transaction['Member ID (U1)']
    console.log(member_id) //prints undefined, expected monkey!
})
```

**Edit** - As @apena pointed out the offending character is a 'ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE' (U+FEFF)

Comment: Makes sense - thats so odd! This is coming from a 3rd party via a csv which I have converted into a JSON.

Comment: not sure how or why that special char is there. but ended up copying that char in the for loop. Thank you!

Comment: @gk103 - glad it worked. As other answers pointed out it is a zero width non-break space.